# Nome di un mobile particolare (nella camera da letto)

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, word-choice, etymology, word-order

Vorrei sapere qual è il nome di questo mobile in italiano.

Quali modi esistono di dare un nome a questo mobile con un significato?

Quali modi esistono di chiamare questo mobile con un nome in modo che, parlando di questo mobile in conversazione, gli altri capiscano di che mobile stiamo parlando?

[image: mobile nella camera da letto, forse una credenza]

Comment: So che il mio commento non è pertinente, ma... ti sei svegliato alle 5.30 del mattino assalito da domande sulla terminologia relativa all'arredamento? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

È piuttosto semplice, si chiama *comò* o *cassettiera*.

*Comò* è un mobile a cassetti specifico per la camera da letto, *cassettiera* è generico, è un mobile a cassetti che può stare in qualsiasi stanza.

Vedi le definizioni qui sotto:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/como

https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/cassettiera.shtml

Treccani parla di due sinonimi, *canterano* e *cassettone*, io li eviterei, *canterano* non lo sento più usare, suona piuttosto desueto, e probabilmente molte persone non lo capirebbero,  *cassettone* va anche bene, si usa, ma meno, a quel che sento.

La cosa migliore è ricordarsi il termine *cassettiera*, e non si sbaglia mai.
È un termine usuale che va bene in tutte le occasioni per qualsiasi mobile a cassetti.

E di qualsiasi dimensione, anche un mobile piccolo.  *Comò* indica un mobile abbastanza grande: un mobiletto piccolo a cassetti non lo si chiama *comò*, anche se sta in camera da letto.

Non so per quale motivo Treccani definisce come *cassettiera* solo una parte interna a cassetti di un mobile, forse una volta era così, poi il termine *cassettiera* si è esteso a mobili a cassetti in genere (basta guardare   tanti siti di arredamento dove si dice sempre *cassettiera* per i mobili a cassetti qualsiasi):

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cassettiera/

Comment: In effetti lo Zingarelli riporta anche la definizione “mobile costituito da più cassetti sovrapposti” (e anzi come prima accezione, mentre la seconda è quella sullo scomparto di un altro mobile). Si vede che è un uso più recente, a cui lo Zingarelli è in generale più aperto del Treccani, a costo a volte di accogliere modismi passeggeri, che poi vengono espunti.

Comment: In effetti anche a me sembra che Treccani tenda a essere più old-fashioned. Chi dice più 'canterano'? A dirlo si fa la figura della nonna, e probabilmente quasi nessuno lo capice più.

Comment: Infatti. D'altronde è anche importante che un dizionario sia depositario dell'italiano di tutti i registri e tutte le epoche.

Comment: è possibile chiamarlo _una commode_?

Comment: Sì, perché pur essendo un termine francese viene usato in Italia. Ma  è un termine un po' più sofisticato, si usa in genere nell'antiquariato, e non è detto che qualsiasi  italiano lo conosca.  Dipende dai contesti e credo dalla regione. Io sono di Napoli, e lì i termini francesi sono comuni, quindi non mi parrebbe strano, ma non so altrove. Come uso quotidiano, meglio *cassettiera* o *comò* . https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commode  Comunque il vocabolario Treccani riporta il termine, https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/commode e pure De Mauro https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/commode

Comment: Io uso cassettone, anzi è stato il primo termine che mi è venuto in mente vedendolo.

Comment: Sì sì, ma infatti, va benissimo, anche cassettone per me è comune, però è più una cosa che mi ricorda l'infanzia, ora lo sento poco. Ma penso che molto sia legato a usanze anche locali, io ora sono a Roma, se fossi ancora a Napoli 'cassettone' credo lo sentirei di più. Credo che ora 'cassettiera' e 'comò' siano più universali, più 'asettici'. Sono i termini che vedo sui siti di tutti i negozi di arredamento, tra l'altro. Se vado in un negozio a Roma per comprare questo mobile e dico 'Vorrei un cassettone', credo che spesso mi guarderebbero con gli occhi sgranati. Ma è solo la mia esperienza.

Comment: Cioè, se entrassi da un antiquario e dicessi:" Vorrei un cassettione dell'800", Ok. Se vado in comune negozio di arredamento moderno e dico "Vorrei un cassettone" in alcuni posti suonerebbe strano. Per cui credo che una persona che non è di madre lingua è meglio che eviti certe sofisticherie, almeno se non ne è padrone, e usi nel dubbio 'cassettiera'.